# GetOldTweets looping through startdate until next

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to collects tweets with GetOldTweets3. I want to loop through a list of dates, so I collect data one day at a time. So har I have the following:

```
import GetOldTweets3 as got    
def tweetScraper(hashtag):
        for i in daterange:
            tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch(hashtag).setSince(i).setUntil(i)
            hashtag_tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
            print(len(hashtag_tweets))
        sleep(5)
```

The problem is that Since and Until cannot be the same date, but must be e.g.:

```
.setSince('2019-02-01').setUntil('2019-02-02')
```

So I need help to figure out how to have the Until date be the day after the Since date. The date list is made up of strings of dates, as GetOldTweets require it to be so.

Comment: if you havent already, go checkout the python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) type. Probably it has the day increment functions and string conversion that you seek :)

Answer (score 0):

Use timedelta of one day:

```
import datetime
def add_day(since_date_str):
    since_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(since_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
    until_date = since_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    until_date_str = str(until_date.date())
    return until_date_str
```

In your loop:

```
tweetCriteria =got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch(hashtag).setSince(i).setUntil(add_day(i))
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. This seems like a good solution. However, I cannot figure out how to add this into the loop. Could you elaborate on how to do so?

Comment: Again, thank you so much for helping! When I run the above, I get this error: "time data '2' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'"

It looks like i treats each number in the date-string individually, rather than the entire string at once.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, no. Both are strings of YYYY-MM-DD. since_date_str = '2019-02-01' and until_date_str = '2019-02-02'. I tried doing a for-loop for until_date_str: "for i in until_date_str: print(i)" and this returns each number individually as well.

Comment: If you loop over a string variable the loop will iterate over the letters, here the "letters" are numbers.